# Does the White House Chief of Staff in the US hold considerable power over others?

Tags: united-states, president, government, bureaucracy

In various TV shows I've seen that the CoS has considerable influence over the executive and is shown to be "more powerful" (in some sense)  than Secretaries (of State, of Defence, etc).
How close is that to reality, in recent Presidential terms?

I know that the CoS has no codified duties and generally it is upto the President to determine what their powers and functions are.